# Visual Studio Regex matching repeated string

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio (2012) Find and replace regex, how can I match a sequence of multiple elements that may be repeated (not just a repeated single character)?

Specifically, I am trying to locate usages of an attribute (`MyAttribute`) on public void methods where there might be multiple lines in between. For example I want to locate both:

```
[MyAttribute]
public void Method1()
```

and

```
[MyAttribute]
[AnotherAttribute]
//A comment
public void Method2()
```

I can find the first case by means of:

```
MyAttribute.*\r?\npublic void
```

but I don't know how to specify for the more general case of potentially multiple lines in between. I tried:

```
MyAttribute(.*\r?\n)*public void
```

but this hangs my VS.

Comment: Try `MyAttribute[^{]*?public\s+void`

Comment: Would it be easier to search for a `[` followed by `MyAttribyte` and ignore the `public void` criteria? This would not work if the attribute is often used on things that are not `public void`. Search for `[MyAttribute` (or for `\[MyAttribute` with regular expressions).

Comment: No.  Actually, I am searching for more specific things after public void  -  but didn't include that in the question because that bit isn't a problem. More generally, my question is:  how to search for something specific (e.g. MyAttribute) and then one or more full or empty lines and then another specific string.

Comment: Have you thought about using reflection?  You could go through the assembly, get all the methods with that attribute...,  it would be kind of weird because you'd need to either be running that assembly or loading it.  It would be much less error prone.

Comment: I agree with @Derek what exactly is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection:

```
     var methods = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .SelectMany( t => t.GetMethods() )
        .Where( m => m.GetCustomAttributes( typeof ( MyAttribute ), true ).Any() && m.IsPublic && m.GetParameters().Length == 0 )
        .ToList();

     methods.ForEach( m => Debug.WriteLine( m.Name ) );
```

You can tweak how you get the Assembly.
This gets all the types on the assembly, then all of the methods, then filters it down to ones with the MyAttribute type, that are public, and have no parameters.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with this information as to whether this is useful or not. :)

Comment: Thanks for that, Derek.  That does actually address what I was trying to do -  even though it is not strictly an answer to the question as posed .  I realise now that Regex search was not the right tool:  but I had got into that mode because I had just written several other Regex statements for finding code patterns I was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?m)^(?:[\s\r]*(?:\[[^]]*\]|//.*)[\s\r]*)+public\s+void[^(]*?\(.*?\)
```

It will match all comments and `[sometext]`-like lines followed with `public void something(something...)`.

A very strange glitch in VS2012 is matching a newline: `\s` usually matches `\r` and `\n`, but in VS2012, we need to add `\r` "manually" to a `[\s\r]` character class.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%5e(%3f%3a%5b%5cs%5cr%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5d*%5c%5d%7c%2f%2f.*)%5b%5cs%5cr%5d*)%2bpublic%5cs%2bvoid%5b%5e(%5d*%3f%5c(.*%3f%5c)&i=Some+text%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2fA+comment%0d%0a%5bMyAttribute%5d%0d%0apublic+void+Method1()%0d%0aand%0d%0a%0d%0a%5bMyAttribute%5d%0d%0a%5bAnotherAttribute%5d%0d%0a%2f%2fA+comment%0d%0apublic+void+Method2())

[image]

Comment: I have updated the answer. I was aware of the `[\s\S]` issue, was not sure `\s` can be the root of this problem.

Comment: So, you talked it over with OmegaMan... and? Please let me know what you need, readability is hardly a code matching regex friend.

Comment: Here is a slightly improved version: `(?m)^(?:[\s\r]*(?:\[[^]]*\]|//.*)[\s\r]*)+public\s+void[^(]*\(.*?\)`. However, without the exact input, it is difficult to optimize further.

Comment: I am grateful for your answer, which works  - but runs VERY slowly on my VS (esp. when applied across a large solution).  I've accepted Derek's answer because, though it does not strictly answer the question as I posed it, it does address my example need, as described.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Visual Studio (2012) Regex...
>   ...search for something specific (e.g. MyAttribute) and then one or more
>   full or empty lines and then another specific string

Within Visual Studio use this

`\[MyAttribute\][\s\r\n\W\w]+?public`

which basically says find the specific string "[MyAttribute]" then find  any spaces or tabs `\s`, carriage returns, line feeds, `\r\n`, non word and word items `\W\w`, for one or more (of the preceding characters items) `+`, then as little (minimal) as possible `?` til it finds the specific word "public".

Here it is running

[image]

### Update

`\S` = `\W\w` - `\S` means any non whitespace character.

So the pattern could be shortened such as

`\[MyAttribute\][\s\r\n\S]+?public`

### Update on Public Void

Change the pattern to

`\[MyAttribute\][\s\r\n\S]+?public\s+void`

to only find "public void".

Comment: That's more readable than stribizhev's answer but it is flawed. If I had a private method with MyAttribute and then, lower in the same file, a public method without the attribute, your regex selects all the code from the attribute to the public method.

Comment: @RichardPawson for some reason an actual space in a regex pattern fails for the "public void" situation. Change it to `public\s+void` or `\[MyAttribute\][\s\r\n\S]+?public\s+void`.

Comment: @RichardPawson the use of `.*` makes the parser look into scenarios (backtracking as regex speak) which frankly don't pay off because *we* know what needs to be matched. Avoiding `.*` and changing it to `.+` makes for smarter patterns and less slowness. (Also see my response to the public void in my comment previous).

Comment: @RichardPawson yes I am seeing some issue...can you provide a slim example text file which has the *all* the permutations and what you want matched.